# TestCafe seems not working a combination of expect + exists + ok(or notOk)

Tags: testing, automated-tests, e2e-testing, testcafe, web-testing

I have been testing UI using TestCafe and I found something weird situation for me.

Here is weird case.

```
// it's passed because I expected...
.expect(
  Selector('.v-menu__content.menuable__content__active')
    .find('.v-list__tile.v-list__tile--link')
    .withText(label).exists
)
.notOk('check')

// but this is passed too though this should fail
.expect(
  Selector('.v-menu__content.menuable__content__active')
    .find('.v-list__tile.v-list__tile--link')
    .withText(label).exists
)
.ok('check')
```

Here I used `await` for this issue.

```
// it was not passed!!! => Yay!
.expect(
  await Selector('.v-menu__content.menuable__content__active')
    .find('.v-list__tile.v-list__tile--link')
    .withText(label).exists
)
.ok('check')
```

I couldn't find specific information from [GitHub](https://github.com/DevExpress/testcafe/issues), can anyone tell me is this what I have to do actually?

Thanks

Answer (score 2):

May be you could rewrite your test like this:

```
const labelSelector = 
  Selector('.vmenu__content.menuable__content__active')
    .find('.v-list__tile.v-list__tile--link')
    .withText(label);

await t
  .expect(labelSelector.exists)
  .notOk({timeout: 30000});

await t
  .expect(labelSelector.exists)
  .ok({timeout: 30000}); // should fail
```

You could also setup explicit timeouts on the TestCafe command-line : [--selector-timeout and --assertion-timeout](https://devexpress.github.io/testcafe/documentation/using-testcafe/command-line-interface.html#--selector-timeout-ms)